# Encrypted text like english text

Tags: javascript, encryption

Is there a method to encrypt text and the output to be a common english/spanish text or alike, and be able to decrypt it too?

I tried the Caesar encryption

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher

```
Plaintext:  THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG    
Ciphertext: QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD
```

but I'd like the output for example:

```
Plaintext:  THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG    
Ciphertext: RADIO LIBRARY MAKE TABLE TIME ON KITCHEN DAY OF
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure this is possible with a specifically crafted one time pad. XOR the plaintext and the target ciphertext and you get the key. `key.length = max(pt.length, ct.length)` This obviously works only for one PT, CT pair.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution. There may be performance issues with having the English or Spanish dictionary in an array, but you may just need common words.

```
function wordSwap(String str){
    var dictionary = Array(a, the, brown, fox, over, ...);
    var swapDictionary = randomizeArray(dictionary);
    var newStr = "";

    str = str.split(' ');
    foreach(str as s){
        var idx = dictionary.indexOf(s);
        newStr += swapDictionary[idx]+" ";
    }

    return newStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jack's answer is pretty straightforward, and matches your Caesar Cipher well, but it's not very secure. It's just a substitution cipher with a much bigger "alphabet". Like your Caesar Cipher, that means it can be broken using frequency analysis. The words THE and AND are pretty common in English. ÉL and LA are extremely common in Spanish. So I look for "words" that show up very commonly in the cipher text and assume that they map to common words in my target language. I continue making guesses based on frequency and context until I work out portions of the message (or even the whole message). If I know this is probably about poodles, and I see a SUNRISE shows up often in the message, maybe I assume that SUNRISE is a poodle and I work from there.

I like it for being simple, but I don't like it so much if I want security.

We could devise a format preserving encryption scheme, which is what you kind of want here, but I'm not familiar with one that is designed to work on such a large domain (it's an area you could investigate though, or ask on http://crypto.stackexchange.com, which would be a better place for this question). The advantage of format preserving encryption is that the resulting message should be the same size as the original message.

But here's another solution that we could use, which is kind of a base-N encoding, where N is the size of our dictionary.

Start with an ordered dictionary and your plaintext. Look up each word in your dictionary and note the index. Use those indexes to create a new message where the word size is based on the number of elements in your dictionary. For simplicity, you could round this up to 64 bits per term, but you could also make each term any arbitrary number of bits if you're willing to do more bit math and let data spill across byte boundaries. Encrypt that message however you like (i.e. AES).

Now we need to encode that back into words. For values less than N-1, we just select that word out of the dictionary. For numbers equal to N-1 or greater, you can use the last word in the dictionary as a marker and then add the next word to it. So say we had a 1000 word dictionary (0..999) from A to ZYRIAN. We could encode 999 as ZYRIAN A and 1000 as ZYRIAN AARDVARK. If we needed to encode larger numbers we can chain. For example ZYRIAN ZYRIAN A is 1998. Of course you'll get better output sizes if you again let data split across byte boundaries, no value is greater than 2*N.

The key here is that we've broken the problem into two problems: a transcoder that allows us convert between arbitrary words and numbers, and encryption, which we can do using any standard encryption scheme.